# Nodejs error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been struggling with the problem presented in the topic for some time. Can anyone help me with that? If I have to clarify something, please ask questions. I've read some potential solutions to this problem, but it didn't work for me. Every clue will be appreciated.
Code:

```
const post = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var options = {
        url,
        headers: {
            "Api-Key": apiKey,
            "Authorization": basicToken
        },
        agentOptions: {
            pfx,
            passphrase: ""
        }
    };

    request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {

        if (error) {
            reject("error");
        } else if (response.status === "403") {
            reject("error");
        } else {
            console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(response)} ${response.status}.`);
            console.log("body: " + body);
            if (body == "")
                body = "{}";

            let output = JSON.parse(body);
            if (output.length == 0)
                reject("no data");

            resolve(output);
        }
    });
});
```

Error logs:

```
(node:10) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
2021-06-14 20:31:18.938 CEST
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
2021-06-14 20:31:18.938 CEST
at ServerResponse.header (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
2021-06-14 20:31:18.938 CEST
at ServerResponse.send (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
2021-06-14 20:31:18.938 CEST
at Object.exports.fulfillments (/workspace/index.js:16:25)
2021-06-14 20:31:18.938 CEST
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Code where I am using express:

```
const index = require("./index.js");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/", async(req, res) => {
    await index.fulfillments(req, res);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: You need to show us the request handler code in Express that has this error because that's where the error is being caused.

Comment: I added the code in the main post

Comment: Can you add the ```index.fulfillments(req, res);``` function too ?

Comment: It would probably take us less than 5 minutes to help you, but we need to see ALL the relevant code in processing the request that has the problem.  So, far you've shown the very beginning and perhaps the very end, but not the middle.  We can't help you (other than wild guesses) unless you disclose ALL the relevant code for this request handler.

Answer (score 0):

We've all had that issue once before xD. Basically, somewhere in your code, you are attempting to set a response header after the response has already been returned.

I suggest taking a look through your reponse (fulfillments) function as it could be as simple as missing a return statement after responding to a request.